# SQL query loading number data as value: set html input as number does not allow it, set html input as text allow it

Tags: php, sql, forms, number-formatting

Am wondering what may solve a problem involving a form to update data saved in a row of my table.
The query work fine with all of the other data excluding a number decimal, here’s the commands:

```
<div>
    <label>money</label>
    <input name="name_money" type="number" min="0.00" step="0.01" placeholder="€ 0,00" value="<?php $row['money'];?>"/>
</div>
```

What seems me really strange is that  it does not load only if I set the  type=”number” while, to have a test, I can correctly see setting type=”text” – by the way can not use this option since it trigger the decimal.

Does some one have any idea or suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: So you need to be able to write decimals into your `<input>`? Try adding `step=".01"` as an attribute. Or whatever amount of decimals you need.

Comment: @rpm192 in my case it already is ok to write decimal in SQL from a text input, unfortunately the problem start saving the data inside the value since no decimals get the SQL

Comment: Make sure that you're using a dot and not a comma. Did adding `step=".01"` change anything?

Comment: @rpm192 yes, I already did it and also tried without. Maybe the issue is anyway related at that. I use echo number_format($row['money'], 2, ',', '.');?> to change the way it is displayed. In the data entry form I charge data using comma and they are stored using point

Comment: @rpm192 it works ok using point instead of comma but in text field, that way it save it correctly but that's completely out of question. can not use that solution which is not standard in my country.... have you any knowlodege about the reasons my system behave that way and how to change it?

Comment: What data type is the column in your database?

Comment: @rpm192  decimal(11,2)

Comment: I could start wondering over that again and again, anyway using value="<?php echo $row['money'];?> - which mean avoiding the number format statement - now it show me the data and allow to save it ok using type="number" | a solution I neither try before becouse in the main form it was not ok, don't really know how and for any possible other error or specific related cause. Maybe should just not code late at night.....